# "Formula analysis error" with Sparkline function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sparklines

I am coming here tonight because I do not understand something about Google Sheets.

I found a [super GSheet file](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FyoaAMW&redir_token=_7kgx7Xe0Rz9nPre0A_U7bZDIot8MTU3NTE0NjE0OEAxNTc1MDU5NzQ4&v=-crraoSMxc0&event=video_description) that can do Gantt planning. So I tried to transpose that into a personal document. Before starting to make some more custom formulas I just tried to copy and paste the formula used for the reference graph ("hatched" graph) and I already have a formula analysis error.

I really do not understand where the problem comes from.

Here is the original formula, functional:

[image: Formula of origin, functional]

And now the same formula in my doc, but that does not work

[image: The same formula in my doc, does not work]

Comment: You can have it here: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n3NemtjI7FjYqq1I10dS6B221PToNC2pU3Q3NTsEgcc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SPARKLINE({SPLIT(REPT("7,";FLOOR((INT(G5)-INT(F5))/7));",")\MOD(INT(G5)-INT(F5);7)};
 {"charttype"\"bar";"color1"\"white";"color2"\"lightgrey"})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's the same (take a look at this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n3NemtjI7FjYqq1I10dS6B221PToNC2pU3Q3NTsEgcc/edit?usp=sharing))

Comment: It's working perfectly. Then it's was just a syntax error ? I find it strange considering that it's working on the original doc :p Thanks a lot @player0 !

Comment: the original doc has US syntax. in your sheet you need EU syntax difference is in ; \ instead of , ;